# How to Determine if Rails Association is Eager Loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

Does anyone know a way to determine if a Rails association has been eager loaded?

My situation:  I have a result set where sometimes one of the associations is eager loaded, and sometimes it isn't.  If it isn't eager-loaded, then I want to look up associations using ActiveRecord's find.  If it is eager loaded, I want to use detect.

For example, say that I have a "has_many" array of shipping_info objects in my item model.  Then:

If item is eager loaded, most efficient load is:

```
item.shipping_infos.detect { |si| si.region == "United States" }
```

If item isn't eager loaded, most efficient load is:

```
item.shipping_infos.where(region: "United States").first
```

But unless I know whether it is eager loaded, I don't know which code to call to get the  record efficiently.  If I use the first method when it wasn't eager loaded, then I have to look up more DB records than necessary.  And if I use the second method when it was eager loaded, then my eager loaded objects are ignored.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`item.shipping_infos.loaded?` will tell you.

I gotta say, though: this path leads to madness... before writing code that tests `loaded?` to decide between `#detect` and `#find`, make sure this instance *really* matters, relative to everything else that's going on.

If this isn't the slowest thing your app does, adding extra code paths adds unnecessary complexity. Just because you might waste a little database effort doesn't mean you need to fix it - it probably doesn't matter in any measurable way.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  I understand where you're coming from.  This particular code happens to be in the most frequently called partial in our entire app, though, so shaving off even microseconds makes a measurable difference.  I'll give #loaded? a try.

Comment: This will only work for has_many associations! In case of belongs_to this call will actually load the other object (so it will be always true)

Comment: @reto to check for this in `has_one`/`belongs_to` associations you can do `item.association(:shipping_info).loaded?` which works similarly.

Added examples and more detail in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69349863/1454001

Comment: good point, although 12 years too late! :D

Answer (score 87):

Use `.association(name).loaded?` on a record.

---

For Rails < 3.1 use `loaded_foo?`.

(It is deprecated since Rails 3.1. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/472.)

Answer (score 27):

I'd suggest using item.association_cache.keys that will provide a list of the eager loaded associations. So you `item.association_cache.keys.include?(:name_of_association)`

Comment: Perfect solution. Dabogert you're the king :)

Comment: Wow, can't believe that I had been missing this. This works for cases where the association is NOT loaded, but there IS an in-memory cache (e.g. when you build object using the association).

Comment: This syntax no longer works in rails 5 (not sure when it changed). It's now `item.association_cached? :name_of_association`.

Answer (score 14):

[`association_cached?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6003257b73e66df8cd00d4014724df1a31761381/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L244) might be a good fit:

```
item.association_cached?(:shipping_infos)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can detect whether or not a single association has been loaded with loaded_*foo*?.  For example, if shipping_info was a belongs_to association, then item.loaded_shipping_info? will return true when it's been eager-loaded.  Oddly, it appears to return nil (rather than false) when it hasn't been loaded (in Rails 2.3.10 anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Solution to this problem should be `foo.association(:bla).loaded?`, BUT it works incorrectly - it checks and marks association as dirty:

```
class Foo; has_one :bla, :autosave => true end
foo.association(:bla).loaded? #=> false
foo.save # saves foo and fires select * from bla
```

So I've added following extension to ActiveRecord:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def association_loaded?(name)
      association_instance_get(name).present?
    end
  end
end
```

and now:

```
class Foo; has_one :bla, :autosave => true end
foo.association_loaded?(:bla) #=> false
foo.save # saves foo
```

Comment: You should double check that this is still a problem and update the answer to scope it to the appropriate Rails versions. I was unable to reproduce.

Comment: Still a problem as of Rails 4.2.6.  Not sure if Rails 5 has it.

Comment: What's the consequence of marking it as dirty? Just one extra select statement? Or is there more harm to it?

Comment: The consequence of the relation being marked incorrectly as dirty is that rails normally no-ops save calls on models that have no dirty attributes.  So you will introduce extra saves and if you're using rails timestamps on the model it'll cause the updated_at times to update when no attributes in the model were actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Bullet gem.](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet). This will tell you when you should and should not use eager loading.

Comment: Bullet has proven really useful, even though I've done very little other DB optimisation yet. At least it gets rid of some unnecessary lines in the console output. ;)

Comment: Bullet plugin link is dead.