# RSpec: Test Scope Eager Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, eager-loading

One of my models' default scope is set to automatically load a related model with `includes()`.  How can I test this functionality with RSpec?  I tried running:

```
Model.includes(:relation).to_sql
```

Hoping I could detect the signature in the SQL, but it only returned this:

```
SELECT "models".* FROM "models"
```

No mention of the relation, it's apparently done with a second query.  How would you recommend testin this?

Comment: Refer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376212/how-to-determine-if-rails-association-is-eager-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go down the route of stubbing the method and setting an expectation.

The pattern would be to add a test double of your model and set the expectation that it receives the `.includes` method call

Testing the actual SQL call created by Rails seems to be more about testing Rails rather than your app and tightly couples it to the implementation.  Testing that the method gets called is a good middle ground, with the knowledge that if it gets called, Rails will do the right thing.

There is a lot more information here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs to better understand the process.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply that, can you give some example code on how to test that the `includes` method was called?  I agree, testing the raw SQL would be a little too close to implementation to be practical.  My intention was to compare it to the SQL generated by another query, restricting it to testing just the results.

Answer (score 0):

`includes(:relation)` will add a `left outer join relations` to your query. This means you can use `relations` in your query without having to `joins(:relations)`.

```
let!(:model) {
  Model.create!( field: 42 )
}
let!(:relation) {
  model.relations.create!( this: "that")
}

it 'includes relation' do
  expect( Model.where("relations.this": "that") ).to contain_exactly(relation)
end
```