# how to check if has_one exists without loading associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple has_one relationship

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :detail
  has_many :courses
end

class Detail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I need to check to see if a user has a detail. Since I can do `User.first.courses.exists?` it was surprising that `User.first.detail.exists?` doesn't work. I could do `!User.first.detail.nil?` but I only need to check if a user detail exists and not load it's very hefty detail model.

What's a good way to check if a has_one association exists without retrieving the entire associated model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `User.first.detail.present?`

Comment: The OP asks to not load the `detail` model. This answer would query and allocate both User and Detail models.

Comment: @James is correct in that this still does the DB query.

I posted my answer above which I think is what OP wants: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69349863/1454001

Answer (score 3):

`Detail.where(user_id: User.first.id).exists?`

This doesn't allocate a `Detail` object if all you want to know is if a user has a detail or not.

Comment: This doesn't work because `detail` is a `has_one` association, so there is no `detail_id` on User.

Comment: @mckeed oh silly me! I'll fix my answer

Answer (score 2):

To check if an association is loaded without hitting the DB you can use:

`model.association(:association_name).loaded?` for `has_one`/`belongs_to` associations and `model.many_things.loaded?` for `has_many` associations.

#### Checking if has_one/belongs_to association has been loaded:

```rb
user = User.find(1)

user.association(:detail).loaded? # => false

user.detail.id # Does DB request to get Detail

user.association(:detail).loaded? # => true
```

###### With Eager loading

Eager loading lets you load the data in advance, so as expected the association is marked as loaded:

```rb
user = User.eager_load(:detail).find(1)
user.detail.loaded? # => true
```

#### Checking if has_many association has been loaded

With has_many associations,

```rb
user = User.find(1)
user.association(:courses).loaded? # => false

user.courses.load # Does DB query to get all users' courses
user.association(:courses).loaded? # => true
```

###### Doing `.first` or some other queries won't always load

Keep in mind that it does not mark as loaded in all cases:

```rb
user.courses.first.id # Does DB query to get first course ID
user.association(:courses).loaded? # => false (still!)
```

This is because it is actually doing a `SELECT * LIMIT 1` query when you do the `.first` for efficiency-sake.

###### With Eager loading

```rb
user = User.eager_load(:courses).find(1)
user.association(:courses).loaded? # => true
```

## When to use the `loaded?` method?

The only use case I can think of is when you don't want to trigger a DB call but you want to check to see if the data has been loaded already and do something with it only if it has.

In my case I wanted to output some data for logging purposes, but only if it was not adding an extra DB query by calling the association.

Comment: This does not actually determine is the association exists, in the sense that a record is persisted in the database. This only confirms if the association has been loaded into memory. Additionally even when `@loaded` is true it does not confirm the existence of a record, meaning count > 0. The most efficient way to confirm both would be to use `exists?` which will run a query that returns a boolean without instantiating the object.

Comment: @engineersmnky as long as you're eager loading with a `has_one` relationship like OP then it does mean count > 0, so it solves the problem, albiet a bit differently l.

Comment: No query. `loaded?` is based on `@loaded` if the data is not loaded no query is executed and `false` is returned. One could have 1M records but this methodology will return `false` if the association has not been called (or `loaded?`) but one could have 0 records and this methodology will return `true` if the association has been called, therefore this does not solve the question posed.

Comment: @engineersmnky I see what you're saying. So yeah you'd need to use another check to see if the model data exists in addition to eager loading and the `loaded?`. Thanks for explaining! Upvoted your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails way it to load the object and check if it's present. But still, you can access the association scope to use it without loading the associated object:

```rb
user = User.find(1)

user.association(:detail).loaded? # => false

# Triggers the SQL you need: just check if a Detail record associated with that user exists.
user.association(:detail).scope.exists?

user.association(:detail).loaded? # => false (we still didn't load the associated object)

user.detail.id # Does DB request to get Detail

user.association(:detail).loaded? # => true
```